# Array of data is not binding in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery

this array of data not binding,can anyoneset it

```
presentProfile = Object {authenticateCode: null,frontendPermission:
    Array(3)
    0:"administrator"
    1:"author"
    2:"contributor" }   

    jQuery.each(presentProfile.frontendPermission, function (index, data) {
           jQuery("#bis_frontend_display_roles").select2("val", data);
        });
```

Comment: You're using `select2` in a wrong way. Have you read [it's documentation](http://select2.github.io/select2/)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
var presentProfile = {
    authenticateCode: null,
    frontendPermission:[{id:0, text:"administrator"},{id:1, text:"author"},{id:2, text:"contributor"}] 
} ;

jQuery("#bis_frontend_display_roles").select2({data: presentProfile.frontendPermission});
```

Comment: then also not binding

Comment: Updated it, have a look.

Comment: i thought that why because its not working, i am using 4.0.0 version of select2